# Summarise columns into percentage of a certain value

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to summarise my data according to a group variable. And having for each variable the percentage of "yes" occuring. So for this example data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                 female = c("yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no"),
                 alcohol = c("yes","no",NA,"no","yes","yes","no","no"))

  group female alcohol
1     a    yes     yes
2     a     no      no
3     a    yes    <NA>
4     a     no      no
5     b    yes     yes
6     b    yes     yes
7     b    yes      no
8     b     no      no
```

The result would be this : (the result could be or a ratio or a percentage)

```
> df_result
  group female alcohol
1     a   0.50    0.33
2     b   0.75    0.50
```

I tried with tidyverse and the summarise function but the fact is that i have a lot of columns and naming them each would be really long

Comment: "i have a lot of columns and naming them each would be really long": look at `across`.  Something like `... summarise(across(-group, function(x) mean(x == 'yes', na.rm = TRUE)))`.  Or convert your data frame to long format.

Comment: @GregorThomas.  Thanks.  Fixed.  if I had a pound for every time I'd made that mistake...

Comment: @Limey one more, add `.by = group` and I think you've got a complete answer. (And with that you can do `across(everything())`

Comment: @BPeif calculating the proportion of a "yes" is the same as testing which equal `'yes`' and taking the mean. So this is a fairly common problem of "mean by group over several columns". With `library(dplyr)` `df |> summarize(across(everything(), \(x) mean(x == 'yes', na.rm = TRUE)), .by = group)` should work. You can see the linked FAQ for other methods and more detail. You can also use the tidyselect helpers to select your columns in many other ways if `everything()` isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thank you it works well ! Just by curiosity, what does the " \\(x)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~mean(.=="yes", na.rm =  TRUE)), .by=group)
  group female   alcohol
1     a   0.50 0.3333333
2     b   0.75 0.5000000
```

Answer (score 1):

in base R

```
prop.table(table(cbind(df[1], stack(df, -1))), c(1,3))[,2,]
     ind
group    female   alcohol
    a 0.5000000 0.3333333
    b 0.7500000 0.5000000
```

---

```
aggregate(.~group, df, \(x)mean(x=='yes', na.rm = TRUE), na.action = na.pass)

  group female   alcohol
1     a   0.50 0.3333333
2     b   0.75 0.5000000
```